# React Native : FlatList does not render

Tags: react-native

I am a newbie to react-native, why does the following FlatList not render my datasource ?

```
  componentDidMount(){            
        var _data = [{title: "Test Title",  timestamp : "2018-10-02:23:11:45" }];

        this.setState({
            isLoading : false,
            dataSource :  { _data }
        });
    }
```

---

```
 render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.body}>
          <View>
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.dataSource}
              renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.title}, {item.timestamp}</Text>}
              keyExtractor={(item,index) => index}
              extraData={this.state.isLoading}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**If I place the object array inline then it works** :

```
data={[
    {title: "Test Title", timestamp : "2018-10-02:23:11:45" }
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
this.setState({
            isLoading : false,
            dataSource :  { _data }
        });
```

You are trying to set `_data` as an object `without` `key` to the `datasource state object`, i.e. *remove the curly brackets*

Just replace it with                 `dataSource :  _data`

Comment: Unbelievable, so simple , I swear I tried this, well now it works. Just needed a second set of eyes. Gracias.

Comment: De nada, no hay problema :)